# Calculation producing whole number instead of a decimal

Tags: c

I have some code:

```c
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  int amount;
  
  // user input for annual income
  printf("Enter your amount: ");
  scanf("%d", &amount);

  if(amount <= 34000)
    amount = amount * .33;

  double new_amount = (double) amount;
  printf("your calculated amount: %.2f\n", new_amout);

  return 0;
}
```

I am trying to take in an integer value and then convert it to a double after making my calculation.  However, when i enter my `int`, it prints a decimal but with no non-integer part.

For example, if my amount is 19522, my code prints 6442.00 instead of 6442.26.

Comment: you declared 'amount' as an int ....

Comment: How could it return 6442.26? `amount` is an int. It doesn't matter if `amount*.33` worth 6442.26, you stored it in a variable (and `int`) that is unable to hold a value such as 6442.26. So, it is rounded to the closest value that can fit in `amount`, which is 6442. And then, when you convert to a double, it is too late. It is just 6442 that you convert to a double. It can't magically recall the lost information of the .26 part. So, 6442 converted to a double is 6442.0

Comment: "_ and then convert it to a double after_"... Try converting the value to double **before** the calculation...

Comment: for this program, I was told to assume that the amount was sent to int, and later in the code I am to convert it to a double, but I am having a hard time doing

Comment: Change `amount = amount * .33` to `double newAmount = amount * .33`... As @chrslg writes, storing back into an `int` will _lose_ the decimal portion of the value.

Comment: store the output in another double var. Its good coding practice to NOT use the same variables for different purposes.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest fix is to change the data type of `amount` to `double` and update the format strings, and eliminate the `new_amount` variable as it doesn't do anything for you.  Also, check that `scanf()` was successful otherwise you may be operating on uninitialized data:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    double amount;
    printf("Enter your amount: ");
    if(scanf("%lf", &amount) != 1) {
        printf("scanf failed\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if(amount <= 34000)
        amount *= .33;

    printf("your calculated amount: %.2lf\n", amount);
}
```